# You've associated your accounts: +100 reputation

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I've just signed up to [Electronics and Robotics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and in a couple of minutes I got +100 on Stack Overflow site (Notification and Rep) <sup>*</sup>.

[image]

I had 16 accounts before signing in to Electronics and Robotics, so it's a little bit suspicious that the StackOverflow +100 trigger kicked in so much lately.

<sup>* is it something I could exploit to gain free reps :)?</sup>

Comment: Try it and let us know :)

Comment: Did you actually get the 100 rep or did it just display the Notification.  If you got to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation does it show the bonus being awarded?

Comment: R U offended by getting additional 100 rep? :) Because I wonder why this question is tagged **bug**?

Comment: @Barry Notification and real sweet Rep :)

Comment: @Robert oh well, I did not find the charity tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Stack Overflow account had been associated in the past, but never received the rep bonus - have a happy holiday :)

Answer (score 19):

There is no exploit, you only get this once per account.

**Example**

- you have a single account with +200 rep and you create another (on a different SE site), you get +100 on both sites. The first to encourage you to associate and participate and the second to give you a little head start.
- next you start and associate an account on a third SE site. You get the +100 on the new account but not on the original account.

So you only get +100 for each SE site once.

Comment: This may be true for a user that has an account on StackOverflow and then links to a new site (total of 2 accounts) but @Systempuntoout has a total of 17 related accounts?

Comment: @Barry, if he got the +100 several times on a single site, it is a bug. But the question has no information on that part.

Comment: @Gamecat It is simple to know: when system.out goes to [his reputation audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation), the second line should read: `-- bonuses (100)`.

Comment: @radp yep, as I said in the question I got the Notification and +100 rep. Anyway my reputation audit says -- bonuses (100).

Comment: @Gamecat As well said by Barry, I have 17 different accounts and I have received that Notification several times but this is the first time I get it on the first site I signed in one year ago: SO.

Comment: @systempuntoout, ok then you got the notification a little late. But still, if you have only one +100 per account, there is no exploit.

Comment: @Gamecat oh, strange but could be.

Comment: Does this process happen when a user has a single account in three different sites  initially and all three are below 200 and say after a year one of them crosses 200 , so does the user get +100 for each of the sites ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with 30 associated sites you can get 3,030 free reputation for Area51 committal purposes.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Case in point: [my associated accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135907?tab=accounts). I don't see anything wrong with that. (It's not like I don't participate in all those sites *at all*. I visit each and every single one of them quite regularly and leave an occasional upvote here and there, [which we definitely do want](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).)

Comment: @RegDwight I wasn't accusing you or anything :)