# Why did my SO rep just jump by 100?

Tags: support, reputation

My rep just went up 100 points.  Not that I am complaining but I received no up votes on questions or answers.  So I'm not sure why.  I did just join the Programming Puzzles stack exchange site today.  Is this some kind of bonus for joining that site?  Some other reason?

UPDATE:  Now it has gone down by 2.  But my reputation tab does not show a downvote.  Solar flares?

Comment: The -2 was a downvote on this question apparently, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob

Comment: @Brandon.  Thanks that down vote shows up in my rep view now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [You've associated your accounts: +100 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72518/youve-associated-your-accounts-100-reputation)

Comment: @lance that dupe predates the dynamic real-time +100 we do today, so it's not quite the same.. different enough to leave alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your accounts are now linked on six different exchange websites, one of which has at least 200 rep.  For example, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983).

Comment: [Also here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72518).

Answer (score 4):

When you have a reputation higher than 199 in a SE site, you will get a bonus of 100 points in any site you have an account, and where you will create an account.
You get the bonus only once per each site, and the bonus is not cumulative: When you reach a reputation higher than 199 in another site, the bonus doesn't become 200.

Answer (score 3):

From [Are the bonuses still given to who registers to more than one Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/are-the-bonuses-still-given-to-who-registers-to-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site):

> When you associate *one or more* sites that have 200+ rep, you get a *single* +100 point bonus on the new site.